# save md5 password in md5 format django?

Tags: mysql, django, hash

i am migrating my database and i have a user table which has password store in md5?So i want to store my password in md5 only and if user enter the password it accepts it.so is there any way i can save my password in md5.
 `say for example my user has a password :-'e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e'`

```
password =request.POST.get('password').strip()
        confirmPassword =request.POST.get('confirmPassword').strip()
        if password != confirmPassword:
            messages.error(request,'password and confim password must be same')
            return render(request, 'templates/sign-up.html')
        if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            messages.error(request, 'This email already exists')
            return render(request, 'templates/sign-up.html')
        new_password = make_password(password)
        staff = False
        superUser = False
        status = True
        authUser = User( password=new_password,
                        username=email, email=email,is_active=status, is_staff=staff, is_superuser=superUser)
        authUser.save()
```

and i want to save that in my auth_user table how can i do that.

Comment: @Terry **SHA256 is not a password hashing algorithm.** The whole purpose of a password hashing algorithm is that it is slow and hard to run in parallel, so attackers need to spend a lot of resources to crack the passwords. SHA256 is both fast and cheap. You need to use a proper password-based key derivation functions, such as PBKDF2, BCrypt or Argon.

Comment: see i m migrating my old cms build in php to django and i have users with passwords in md5 so i just want to copy and paste those passwords but meanwhile i want django to know that its an md5 password

Comment: Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use a function such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt` or similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django has an MD5 password hasher built in, just add it to the bottom of the `PASSWORD_HASHERS` setting:

```
PASSWORD_HASHERS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2SHA1PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.Argon2PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptSHA256PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptPasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.UnsaltedMD5PasswordHasher',
]
```

This way Django will check the password using unsalted MD5, but when a user logs in successfully, the password is automatically updated to use a stronger hash.

However, for security purposes, it is highly recommended that you write a [wrapped hasher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/passwords/#password-upgrading-without-requiring-a-login) that will hash the md5 hash using a stronger password hashing algorithm. By wrapping the md5 hash, you can simply import the old hashes and save them in a secure way, without the need for users to log in before it takes effect.

Comment: will that work for new users like i m migrating my old cms build in php to django so i will be just copying the password from database nd saving them into my new database

Comment: Django will recognise a plain string with 32 characters as unsalted MD5, so old users can log in, but for all new users it will use the algorithm that's first in the `PASSWORD_HASHERS` setting. By putting `PBKDF2` at the top of the list, you ensure that passwords of new users, and old users who have logged in on the new system, are protected using a secure password hashing algorithm.